# How to force LVN_HOTTRACK to always fire even when a CMenu is currently open

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, mfc, clistctrl

This is my scenario:

1. I have a `CListCtrl` which I show a CMenu upon right click, by using [`CMenu::TrackPopupMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648002(v=vs.85).aspx).
2. And then, I also have the event handler `LVN_HOTTRACK` in which I store the current item index of the list control, which updates it every mouse move.
3. Next, on the menu items of `CMenu` mentioned in #1, I have the `UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` event handler, where I check some conditions, then enable/disable the corresponding menu item.

Now, `LVN_HOTTRACK` works as expected, **except when the `CMenu` is shown/open**. I tested this by updating the title bar to "0" on `UPDATE_COMMAND_UI`, while I set it to "1" during `LVN_HOTTRACK`, and noticed that no matter how many times I move the mouse while the menu is open, it never updates to "1".

Additional info:
I tried calling `SetForegroundWindow()` first before calling `TrackPopupMenu()` and behavior is the same.

**EDIT:**
My question would be:
How would I let the `LVN_HOTTRACK` fire **always**, that it would not be blocked by the menu being open?

What I'm trying to do is enable/disable the menu item, which are "Move up", which switches the selected list item with the item above it, and "Move down" which switches with the list item below.

The customer requirement is that I should have a context/right-click menu, and not have buttons to switch items.

If the selected list item is the topmost item, "Move up" should be disabled, and if the selected list item is the bottom most item, "Move down" should be disabled. And enabling/disabling these menu items as far as I understand is done in **`UPDATE_COMMAND_UI`**.

Comment: Why do you need hot tracking while the menu is open?

Comment: Windows explorer also stops hot tracking when menu is open.

Comment: Er, what is your question?

Comment: @IInspectable I think he wonders why hottracking is suspended while the popup menu is open.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: I can guess at probably a hundred different questions, the OP may have wanted to ask. The point is, that questions on Stack Overflow should not have us guess. If you want to ask a question, do ask a question.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it the menu window (an internal popup controlled by the system) performs a mouse capture, your list is not going to receive any mouse related events until that goes away.